# Elixir/Phoenix - limiting number of friends in relationship loop

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this code in my template:

```
   <%= for user <- @users do %>  
    <%= user.name %>  
      <%= for friend <- user.friends do %>
             <%= friend.name %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

It takes all users and gives user's name and list all his friends (relationships).
I want to limit it to 3 friends and count all other friends, so I could have something like this:

User One:

- Friend One
- Friend Two
- Friend Three
- 14 more

User Two:

- Friend One
- Friend Two
- Friend Three
- 0 more

How can it be accomplished?

I was thinking about limiting it in preload, but that will limit my main query..

Comment: If you are using Phoenix, you should do this at the DB layer with Ecto.

Comment: If you want a convenient approach for the developer, look at this library: https://hex.pm/packages/paginator. This can tell you the total count and you can configure the "page size" - it would be 3 in your case. As a bonus, using this library will open the possibility of adding a "show more" clickable element to show, e.g. the next 3 friends. I think this will be easier than writing your own (2) custom queries.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a question about Phoenix really: it's more about dealing with enumerables in Elixir.

If you want to take the first `n` members of an enumerable, use [`Enum.take/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#take/2), e.g.

```
iex> friends = ["a" , "b", "c", "d", "e"]
iex> Enum.take(friends, 3)
["a" , "b", "c"]
```

When you're dealing with a database query, however, you do need to think more about performance.  In this case, I would recommend that you execute 2 separate queries: one query that enforces a `LIMIT` for the records you wish to display and a second query that does a `COUNT` operation so you know how many additional records exist (if any).

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#functions

Comment: I'm aware of Enum.take, but it should be a list, right? I want to get some extra info from each user, like avatar for example, so in this case does it work?

Comment: The `Enum` functions operate on any data structure that implements the `Enumerable` protocol.  That includes lists.